# Problem painting objects in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, texture-painting

I can paint any model in blender internal render But mistakes occurs while trying painting in blender game engine. The following are the steps taken by me to paint a model in blender game engine.

1) Switched to blender game engine with ramps, nodes and shaders deselected.
2) Spited window into two parts and changed one window as UV image editor.
3) Unwrapped the model and add texture to UV image editor.
4) Switched from object to texture paint mode and view port shading to texture.
5) Added a paint slot.

And after doing all these steps when I start painting, nothing happens. So as a solution for now, I decided to paint my model in blender internal render and use that image in blender game engine. I just want to know where I am going wrong. It would be very helpful if anyone would write the correct steps to paint a model in blender game engine.

I'm using blender 2.75a

Comment: The BGE does not provide any "painting" support. You need to implement them all by yourself. - If you mean the "Texture Paint" mode -> this is Blender not BGE. The engine setting in the main menu just toggles some UI elements of Blender. Btw. you need to setup a texture in the texture tab too.

Comment: I tried my best to find a way but what you said was right